# Urho3d skynode unwanted artefacts

Tags: android, skybox, urhosharp, urho3d

I have a problem with a sky node in the UrhoSharp 1.4.47 sprite engine running on Android smartphones and tablets. iPhones don't have this problem.

When looking at the sky node exactly in the direction up ={0,1,0} or left ={1,0,0} or right or back or front, the sprite engine shows a white unwanted Artefact.

[image][image]

The sky node texture is a cube map, so the problem is when I look exactly at the normal of a face.

```
<cubemap>
<face name="BrightDay1_PosX.dds" />
<face name="BrightDay1_NegX.dds" />
<face name="BrightDay1_PosY.dds" />
<face name="BrightDay1_NegY.dds" />
<face name="BrightDay1_PosZ.dds" />
<face name="BrightDay1_NegZ.dds" />
<quality low="0" />
</cubemap>
```

The code is in a Xamarin Studio C# project.:

```
using Urho;
namespace Play
{
public class Level2
{
    public Level2() { }
    void CreateSky()
    {
        var cache = Application.Current.ResourceCache;
        Node skyNode = scene.CreateChild("Sky");
        skyNode.SetScale(500.0f); 
        Skybox skybox = skyNode.CreateComponent<Skybox>();
        skybox.Model = cache.GetModel("Models/Box.mdl");
        skybox.SetMaterial(cache.GetMaterial("Materials/Skybox.xml"));
}
}
```